# Visual Studio debugger step into compiled source

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, step-into

I want to be able to step into the source code that is behind a 3rd party (not .Net framework) dll referenced in my own user code. I've done this before but can't now. When I try to step in, VS says there is no source available and would I like to go to disassembly.

How do I get VS to ask me to link to the source code to step into?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would need is the debug file (.pdb) of the assembly you want to step into.

The debug file contains all the information about every line, every method, class and variable, but it does not guarantee that you would successfully be able to "step into" the actual 3rd party source code as originally developed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the framework source code, then this should help you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Comment: I clarified my question - it is not a .Net framework dll. Thanks for this link though. Cheers